# When do we get class X can't be cast to class X kind of exceptions?

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3

When do we get **class X can't be cast to class X** kind of exceptions?
We are trying to write to Amazon S3 using HDFS Api. 
We are using org.apache.hadoop:hdfs-aws:3.1.0 and hadoop-client:3.1.0.

When we deploy the dataflow, Agent's Java process launches thread to write to Amazon S3. First time it works absolutely fine without any exception.
When we undeploy and deploy the dataflow again (2nd time: i.e. without restarting the agent), code throws below exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:135)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3353)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3403)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3371)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:477)
at com.informatica.binge.targets.hdfs_s3.BingeOutputAmazonS3.createFile(BingeOutputAmazonS3.java:313)
at com.informatica.binge.targets.hdfs_s3.HDFSRolloverBase.open(HDFSRolloverBase.java:118)
at com.informatica.binge.targets.hdfs_s3.BingeHDFSTargetDelgator.open(BingeHDFSTargetDelgator.java:78)
at com.informatica.vds.writer.TargetWrapper.run(TargetWrapper.java:521)
```

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    ... 9 more
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AStorageStatistics cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AStorageStatistics
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.createStorageStatistics(S3AFileSystem.java:358)**
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.(S3AFileSystem.java:191)
    ... 14 more

We have suspicion that S3StorageStatistics class is being loaded twice. We have checked classpath also, there is no duplicate jar present in CLASSPATH for this class. 
Your inputs are most welcome.

Regards,

Comment: Two different jars would have same class with same package?

Comment: It is not usually caused by two jars on the same classpath (that would only cause on instance to be loaded, although could result in other problems), but having the class loaded (possibly from the same jar) through **different** classloaders.